# spring boot + security + jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

***Hi,I build a project with spring boot & spring security. Now, I want to provider the login restfull service for Jquery.ajax({...}); And I want to:***

1. process the login request from HTML page (like the `<form>` submit).
2. automatic to check session timeout when HTML page request, redirect timeout to login page.
3. process the login request from Ajax.
4. automatic to check the login state when Ajax request.

***I coding like this***

## SecurityConfig

> extends from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();

    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
        String requestType = request.getHeader("x-requested-with");
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(requestType)) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            response.getWriter().print("{\"invalid_session\": true}");
            response.getWriter().flush();
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("/security/login");
        }
    });

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/security/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/reader/**").hasRole("READER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            // session time out
            .and().sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/security/session_timeout")

            .and().cors()

            // login
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .failureHandler(faildHandler)
            .loginPage("/security/login")
            .permitAll()

            // logout
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(readerRepository::findOne);
}
```

***I have two handlers to process AuthenticationSuccess and AuthenticationFailure***.

## FailureHandler

> extends from SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("Failed to auth.");
    String requestType = request.getHeader("x-requested-with");
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(requestType)) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.getWriter().print("{\"success\": false}");
    } else {
        setDefaultFailureUrl("/security/login?error=true");
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
}
```

## SuccessHandler

> extends from SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("Success to auth.");
    String requestType = request.getHeader("x-requested-with");
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(requestType)) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.getWriter().print("{\"success\": true}");
    } else {
        setDefaultTargetUrl("/index/index");
        setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(true);
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

## Controller

> base RequestMapping is '/security'

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public String login(@RequestParam(value = "error", defaultValue = "false") boolean error, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("error", error);
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping("/session_timeout")
public void sessionTimeout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("session was timeout.");
    if (request.getHeader("x-requested-with") != null) {
        // handler for ajax
        response.getWriter().print("{\"sessionTimeout\": true}");
        response.getWriter().close();
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("login");
    }
}
```

***When I test in page(thymeleaf), All of worked.***
***but.. when I use Jquery Ajax.***
***The issure:***

When I used Jquery.ajax({}) API to send the request, the request can not be get to server. How to write ajax request with jquery, I tried a lot of Jquery methods, page has no response code in console. Is the spring security not support ajax？

Comment: Can you provide your ajax javascript code as well as the server response status code please?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Fan, I fixed it. I rewrote the login authentication:

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userReq.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
if (token.isAuthenticated()) {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
    return true;
}
```

Do auth with AuthenticationManager and it injected from spring.

If success to auth, I will return the sessionid to the client and client saved in cookie, when client do request, the client always stats sessionid at the end of the url requested by ajax.
If failed to auth, I wile return agreed error code.

eg:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://test:port/project/list;jsessionid=' + jessionid,
   ...
})
```

But I do not think so is good job like this. It's very troublesome, In the client,I need to check every response code is it right or not for every request. Is any better ways to solve this ensure??

by the way, the Client(Browser + Ajax) and Server(Spring mvc) are separate.

Comment: Hey Tony, I don't think you need to put the `jsessionid` as a part of the ajax request. The `jsessionid` cookie is automatically getting send to the server as a part of the request header. I have a github repository about spring boot and JWT authentication. The code in there might be helpful to you. Here is the repo's url: https://github.com/bfwg/springboot-jwt-starter